# I don't understand why my Css code for background-image does not work

Tags: html, css, image, background

It seems like a very easy task and that's exactly how it is done on some websites with examples but it just does not work for me!

My folder is like this:

```
project
   resources
      css
         index.css
      images
         pattern.jpeg
         other.jpeg
         another.jpeg
   index.html
```

I need to make a background for some text.
CSS:

```
#company-name{
   background-image: url("resources/images/pattern.jpeg");
}
```

html:
`<h1 id="company-name">Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</h1>`

My html can see the picture, i've checked it by putting it in here:

```
<img src="resources/images/hacksaw.jpeg"/>
```

just in src"" - and the picture was shown normally as it is supposed to.

Also just to check if CSS can understand my ID from HTML - instead of backbround-image - I chenged the color and it did work so ID is fine.

Comment: have you tried background-image: url("../images/pattern.jpeg");

Comment: Or `url("/images/pattern.jpeg")`

Comment: Your CSS file is saved under a different folder than your HTML file, so the path has to be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Remember your CSS and HTML are accessing the image from different positions in the project. The index.html and the resources folder are on the same level so can be reached using the path you've provided.

In order to locate the image from the css, you'll either need to begin your search from the root like so:

```
background-image: url('/resources/images/pattern.jpeg');
```

or begin by coming out of the css directory like so:

```
background-image: url('../images/pattern.jpeg');
```